# Orientation in iPhone

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have been working for iphone for about like 1 month and i want to know that is their any method by which we can set the orientation of the components, like when the device is turned in landscape left or right or in portrait mode then the components must set their view accordingly.

Please help me out regarding this
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Override `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` in a view controller.

```
// MyViewController.m
...
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if ( [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait )
    {
        // If the device orientation is portrait, do stuff here.
    }

    else if ( [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscape )
    {
        // If the device orientation is landscape, do stuff here.
    }
}
...
```